# I'm getting a CORS error in my react app through my nginx proxy even when I set my headers?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-config

I'm trying to access my API data through an axios GET request in my React app. Given the error below, the problem stems from my NGINX config. (I'm assuming from the traceback error but I could be wrong which is why I'm here)

Browser error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://app.url.io/path/' from origin 

'http://localhost:4000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-

Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 

'http://localhost:4000, http://localhost:4000', but only one is allowed.
```

Here is the location of what I'm trying to solve:

```
    location /tickers/ {
      default_type  application/json;
      proxy_set_header Content-Location  /tickers/$upstream_http_content_location;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '$http_origin' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified->      proxy_set_header  Connection "";
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/security?select=symbol,company;
        }
}
```

Just incase, I've added my full NGINX config file, maybe the error originates from somewhere other than location?

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://app.url.io$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name app.url.io www.app.url.io;

    # Lets Encrypt parameters
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/url/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/url/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        alias /path/app/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }

    location /tickers/ {
      default_type  application/json;
      proxy_set_header Content-Location  /tickers/$upstream_http_content_location;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '$http_origin' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified->      proxy_set_header  Connection "";
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/security?select=symbol,company;
        }
}
```

How can I fix my NGINX error and allow only one origin?

Comment: Okay all I had to do was to delete the CORS origin header in my location file, but I'm not sure why that solved it, I don't know where the other header is coming from.